# How to create a "duration" column from two "dates" columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns ("basecamp_date" and "highpoint_date") in my "expeditions" dataframe, they have a start date (basecamp_date) and an end date ("highpoint_date") and I would like to create a new column that expresses the duration between these two dates but I have no idea how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) convert columns to datetimes and then subtrat columns with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for days:

```
file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv"
expeditions = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['basecamp_date','highpoint_date'])
    
expeditions['diff'] = expeditions['highpoint_date'].sub(expeditions['basecamp_date']).dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those columns to datetime and then subtract them to get the duration:

```
tstart = pd.to_datetime(expeditions['basecamp_date'])
tend = pd.to_datetime(expeditions['highpoint_date'])

expeditions['duration'])= pd.Timedelta(tend - tstart)
```